# VueJS: something wrong with my component when it is clicked on

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, components, click

I am working my first project with VueJS and i have a problem with my component.
My project is an chat app, and i am creating a loading component for the messages. This is how the component works: when user enters a conversation, the component shows, and when all the messages are loaded, it disappear.

Everything works fine, but the problem is when i click on the component, it stops working. It does not dissapear. The only way for it to dissappear is to enter another conversation.

```
<loading-message
   v-if="showLoadingMessages"
/>
```

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem. I try to use style: pointer-events: none but still not work.

Comment: Can you add more of your code? Maybe some other component above is getting a click event that's making showLoadingMessages true?